# No ad-hoc compatible Wifi dongle

Tags: wifi, wifi-direct

I've just bought the Edimax EW-7811UN Nano wifi dongle and I am having difficulties creating an ad-hoc connection between my macbook and the raspberry pi.

I have read conflicting information regarding the compatibility of my dongle. Has anyone managed to get it to work in an ad-hoc context ?

Are there other dongles **known** to be ad-hoc compatible ?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm slightly curious to know why you want an ad-hoc connection when you are using your Macbook to post here (presumably) and will want to connect your Pi to the 'Net in order to get package updates.  I presume both your Pi and your Macbook will be connecting to a modem/router so there is no need for an ad-hoc link between them.  Though, in hindsight, I suppose you may be taking them away from your Home LAN to somewhere where there is no network (or not one that you trust...!) 8-)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have an RTL8188-based adapter, you could simply do this:

```
ifconfig wlan0 up              # Unnecessary?
iwconfig wlan0 mode ad-hoc     # The secret sauce
iwconfig wlan0 essid "My WiFi Name"
ifconfig wlan0 192.168.1.1 netmask 255.255.255.0
```

Your dongle has an RTL8188CUS chipset. Give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Hi **EDIMAX 7811UN** doesn't support Ad-Hoc mode past the Linux Kernel versions **3.9+** . This has been checked by me and suggest shifting to **Ralink** based WiFi Dongles. For further information I put this [query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34157743/raspberry-pi-and-edimax-7811un-incompatibility-in-ad-hoc-mode/34458131#34458131) for reference.

I have to work with RPis and WiFi in ad-hoc modes everyday and it makes sense to buy the right WiFi adapter depending on modes you want it to work with. Also I think old **Raspbian Versions 2012** can work with the **Edimax** but that doesn't seem like a plausible solution on a long run.

## Major UPDATE

with **Debian Wheezy 7.10** firmware Update, the **EDIMAX** adapters are now Ad-Hoc Compatible. This has been Tested and Checked today personally!